# Why I cant use $(this) in Success Function of jquery in case of ajax request?

Tags: jquery

When click on label I write code for ajax request and in `succeess` function I write code for change it's class by using `$(this)` but its not working. Why? and How to achieve that?

Comment: set this in a varible then use this variable in sucess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In function after success of ajax request I used like this.

```
     function (result,clickedElement)
     {

         if (result == "True")
         {

             $(clickedElement).removeClass("myclass").addClass("Yourclass");

         }
     }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can save a reference to the label inside success function scope. Like this:

```
$("label or whatever selector you need").click(function(){
    var $label = $(this); 

    //your code goes here

    $.ajax().done(function(data){
        //use $label here
    );
});
```

Comment: This tells the OP how to solve the problem, but not that the value of "this" is changed to the AJAX settings within jQuery AJAX callbacks.

Comment: +1, it's a good habit to save `$(this)` off into a variable any time you need to access it multiple times or in another scope.  I use `$this` as my variable naming convention.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I got another solution also.

Comment: I used clickedelement as another parameter in return function with data. By that I get clickeed element